# Gnome Terminal to have the same color change, based on the background, as Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, desktop-background

This is a silly question, but I would like to know if it is possible, as the title says, to make Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu to change its background color (default purple) to a color based on the background, much like how Unity works for its left-side bar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

#### Change the colour

Using something like [KColor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kcolorchooser/) chooser, select the colour you want. Then go to Profile Preferences under 'Edit', uncheck *'Use ... system Theme'*,  and set the colours you want under 'Custom':
[image]

#### Other backgrounds

Under 'Background':
[image]

You can set an image you want, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZHCx.png) *(as a repeating pattern)* and green text works nicely for an 'old computer' effect - note the Transparency level sometimes seem s to affect image backgrounds.

You can also set a transparent background, which will will use the colour set in Colors above as the base for the transparent background.